# Given a N number counto from 1 to n and n to 1 recursive method java

Tags: java, recursion

For a programming assigment:
Create a recursive method in java that for example for n = 5 returns
1
.2
..3
...4
....5
...4
..3
.2
1
(let the point be spaces or tabs)this has been quite a headache im just started this course so im in beginner level and so far i have this

```
public String Esc(int n){
if (n <= 1) 
    return ""+n;
else
    return n + "\n" + Esc(n - 1) + "\n" + n;
}
```

that returns

5
4
3
2
1
2
3
4
5
so im not even close and im still missing the spaces problem
thanks for helping

Comment: The output you need is the same as the output you say you have. What is the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by "spaces problem"? It appears your output is the same as the desired output, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Tips: Firstly, put a little effort into the question. Was it really that hard to put the correct expected output up? Instead, you failed and put the same output as the incorrect one, and then failed again because you didn't do the spacing. Really? Fix it before you post it. You confused people. Secondly, go through your code. Go through it step by step and look at what happens. You'll then realize how to do the opposite and get it right.

Comment: I gave you the correct solution. Please try and understand why my code works the way expected. I don't know where you're at as a beginner, but hopefully everything I said was easy enough to understand and I didn't not explain anything I should have. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Edited according to your changes working good now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

You pass in your value `n` twice. The reason is that you use `n1` to print from **`1 to n`**, and you then use `n2` to print from **`n to 1`**. You also pass in a `boolean` flag that you make true once you switch the printing order.

Further more, you use `n2` to reverse the value of `n1` when printing such that:

```
n1 = 5, print 1
n1 = 4, print 2
// ....
```

This is done by the formula `n2 + 1 - n1` as demonstrated bellow.

Since you said in the comments that you cannot use loops, I made the printing of dots into another recursive function.

Here is the result:

```
public static void printDots(int val, int condition) { 
    if(val < condition - 1) { 
        System.out.print("."); 
        printDots(val + 1, condition);
    } 
}

public static void Esc(int n1, int n2, boolean reverse) {
    int val = (n2 + 1 - n1);      // this gives 1 for n, 2 for n-1, 3 for n-2 etc.
    if (n1 > 1 && !reverse) {     // print from 1 to n 
        printDots(0, val);        // print dots
        System.out.println(val);
        Esc(n1 - 1, n2, reverse);
    } else if (n1 <= n2) {        // print from n to 1
        reverse = true;
        printDots(0, val);        // print dots
        System.out.println(val);
        Esc(n1 + 1, n2, reverse);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Esc(5, 5, false);
}
```

If you want to use the exact method signature you stated in your question, you can wrap the method I gave you above inside your method:

```
void Esc(int n) {
    Esc(5, 5, false);
}
```

And then call `Esc(5)` from your `main()`. You can name the methods the same because java supports [**`method overloading`**](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=284)

[**`Here is a running example`**](http://ideone.com/qg9CUk)

Output:

```
1
.2
..3
...4
....5
...4
..3
.2
1
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake is from 1 to n and n to 1 with certain amount of spaces before the number already corrected the desired output

Comment: thats perfect just that I have to use a recursive method for everything so cant use whiles and fors, for anything

Comment: Well you can easily convert a loop into a recursive method... `public static void forLoopRecursive(int val, int condition) { 
 if(val < condition) { 
  System.out.print("."); 
  forLoopRecursive(val + 1, condition);
 } 
}` Take a look at this example: http://ideone.com/qg9CUk

Comment: @PabloDelgado look at my edited answer and the link to the example.. I think it does everything you need.

Comment: Overkill on a simple exercise, unnecessary if conditions. It's a simple function that makes one comparison, print's a number twice and recurses. There's a LOT of useless code here, check other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use an accumulator.

```
class Test {

    public static String esc(int n, String accum) {
        if(n == 1) {
            return accum;
        }
        int nMinusOne = n -1;
        return esc(nMinusOne, nMinusOne + "\n" + accum + "\n" + nMinusOne);
    }

    public static String esc(int n) {
        return esc(n, "" + n);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(esc(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: also im stick in the part of adding the spaces to each number

Comment: +1 for a good, working solution that doesn't use a field for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest and easiest:

Demo: [**Press Start**](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/147012)

Code ( first call set m to zero - see in the demo):

```
public static String Esc(int n, int m){
    m = m + 1;
    String s = "";
    for ( int i= 0; i< (m-1); i++ ) s += '.';
    if (n == m) return s + m;
    return s + m + "\n" + Esc(n,m) + "\n" + s + m;
}
```

And even shorter:

```
public static String Esc(int n, int m) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i= 0; i< (m); i++) s += '.';
    return n == m+1 ? s+(m+1) : s+(m+1)+"\n"+ Esc(n,m+1) +"\n"+s+(m+1);
}
```

And Even Shorter and without a for loop!! Demo: [**Press Start**](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/147034)

```
public static String Esc(int n, int m) {
   String s = new String(new char[m]).replace("\0", ".");
   return n == m+1 ? s+(m+1) : s+(m+1)+"\n"+ Esc(n,m+1) +"\n"+s+(m+1);
}
```

Usage:

```
Esc(5, 0);
```

Comment: great just need a way to turn that for into a recursive method too

Comment: its recursive... what do you mean? if you want to avoid the for loop you will have to add another method.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to do what you were doing, except backward. The way I found to do it was to basically have a counter going UP to the number `n` instead of going DOWN from `n` to `1`.

Like this:

```
public static String esc(int n) {
    return esc(1, n); // start at 1, go to n
}

// i counts from 1 to n and then stops at n
public static String esc(int i, int n) {
    if (i == n) {
        return getDots(i - 1) + i; // base case
    }
    else {
        return getDots(i - 1) + i + "\n" + esc(i + 1, n) + "\n" + getDots(i - 1) + i;
    }
}

// this method just generates n number of dots for the spacing
public static String getDots(int n) {
    String dots = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dots += ".";
    }
    return dots;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(esc(5)); // call the function
}
```

So you can see that I recursively call the function using `esc(i + 1, n)` instead of `n - 1`. I'm counting `i` up by `1` each time until I reach `n`.

As for the use of the `getDots` method: The dots in front of each of the number happens to be that number subtract 1. So whenever the number is displayed (which is `i`), just display `i - 1` dots in front of it.

Output:

```
1
.2
..3
...4
....5
...4
..3
.2
1
```

Comment: this is great just need to turn the method for calling the dots into a recursive method without using the for

Comment: +1: @PabloDelgado this is the best way out of the provided answers that show what you need to do. If you need the `printDots` to be recursive just use the technique I showed you in my answer. It's quite simple.

Comment: @PabloDelgado Seriously? You don't accept my answer because printing the dots isn't recursive as well? You're just leeching for an exact answer to your homework assignment. You copying nem's code is a bad idea because it's more complicated than it needs to be with the extra boolean parameter. His answer is fine and it works, but I guarantee you that you didn't even try and look at the code. You copied, pasted, looked at the output and then said "YES IT'S SOLVED". That's pathetic. You could have easily done the dots by yourself. My answer provided the answer to the question. Hope you get a 0.

Comment: I would mark yours as well but  this only let me to mark just one answer as correct thanks anyways this has been very helpful also I dont have the reputation to go +1 yet so sorry if i cant give you enough thanks for your work

Comment: @PabloDelgado It's not about me needing more reputation. It's about how you choose which answers "help" you. You just plagiarized your assignment and you don't deserve the marks you'll get. You didn't just need help conceptually, you needed an exact answer.

Comment: @PedroBorges I over complicated things? Your answer is ridiculous. You made the max value a FIELD. That's so dumb. There's no variability with your method and it's just a silly way of doing it. And if you think my approach is over complicated, you are just a bit slow. Yours is the same approach except you use a field. That's insane to say mine is worse.

Comment: @nem Yeah I was wondering why everyone was negative when they had correct, good solutions lol.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Assignment {
   private static int top;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       top = 5;

       recurse("", 1);
   }

   public static void recurse(String dots, int value) {
       System.out.println(dots + value);
       if (value == top) return;
       recurse(dots + '.', value + 1);
       System.out.println(dots + value);
   }
}
```

It executes like this:

```
recurse("", 1) {
1  print 1
   recurse(".", 2) {
.2    print .2
      recurse("..", 3) {
..3      print ..3
         recurse("...", 4) {
...4        print ...4
            recurse("....", 5) {
....5           print ....5
                return
            }
...4        print ...4
         }
..3      print ..3
      }
.2    print .2
   }
1  print 1
}
```

Now run it in the debugger to learn how it actually works.

Comment: I can do this what i need is the opposite and with spaces for each number

Comment: It missed a static modifier in the top attribute, coding by memory, no compiler at hand... furthermore it's a homework assignment, should leave something for the student no?

Comment: You're leaving it up to the student to change a modifier? There's no point in that lol that has nothing to do with the assignment. You didn't need to add that comment. Could have just left it at the no compiler thing.